# creating a csv of expiring AD users with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've created the powershell script below. It works fine but I would like to have it return the manager of the user. It appears that the object returned but the search-adaccount doesn't do this. Can anyone help with this? Thanks

```
$UserList = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -UsersOnly -TimeSpan 07.00:00:00 | Select-Object name,                   AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate, UserPrincipalName 
$ReportName = "C:\Users\administrator\desktop\ExpiringUsers-7DayReport.csv" 
$UserList | Export-CSV $ReportName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Search-ADAccount` might not *directly* give you what need but a simple pipe into `Get-AdUser` will get the rest for you.

```
$UserList = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -UsersOnly -TimeSpan 07.00:00:00 | 
     Get-ADUser -Properties Manager,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate | 
     Select-Object Name,Manager,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,UserPrincipalName
$ReportName = "C:\Users\administrator\desktop\ExpiringUsers-7DayReport.csv" 
$UserList | Export-CSV $ReportName
```

Several of the properties you are looking for are not standard in the properties of `Get-AdUser` so we need to ensure the are gather with `-Properties`.

**Update from comment**

If you wanted the manager's name and not the dn you need to extract it much in the same we did with the results from `Search-ADAccount`. One way to do this would be to change the `Select` line as follows:

```
Select-Object Name,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,UserPrincipalName,@{Name="Manager Name";Expression={$_.Manager | Get-Aduser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name}}
```

Make a calculated property called `Manager Name` ( Cannot use `manager` since there is already a property with that name. ). Take the manager and pipe it into `Get-Aduser` and just extract the name property.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it possible to return the Name of the manager rather than the Distinguished Name?